# How to update month in date column compare two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to update new column based on using columns (dates) and difference between months, please suggest proper query.

I tried with this code, but did not get the proper result:

```
DECLARE @MAXDATE datetime2
SET @MAXDATE = GETDATE()
SELECT @MAXDATE

UPDATE PO_History
SET diff_UOM_ksa = X.RN
FROM 
    (SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, [PO Date], @MAXDATE) RN
     FROM PO_History) X
```

Results:

```
p1                        p2                         result (diff months)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-04-01 00:00:00.000   2022-04-01 00:00:00.000    12
```

Answer (score 3):

Kind of like below maybe... the inner join is unnecessary.

```
DECLARE @MAXDATE datetime2
set @MAXDATE = getdate()
select @MAXDATE


UPDATE PO_History
SET diff_UOM_ksa =  DATEDIFF(MONTH, [PO Date],@MAXDATE)
```